# MS access based application / db testing using jmeter or loadrunner

Tags: ms-access, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, loadrunner

May i ask if anyone have done any concurrent user test for ms access based db/application. I understand that it is not a typical client / server architecture however still wondering if any method available to simulate multiple users. Thanks

no information available

Answer (score 0):

MS Access is a file-based database like [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) and it assumes that only one local application will be using it as a backend database so I fail to see any viable "concurrent user test" scenarios.

So I can think of the following options:

1. If you're trying to conduct the load onto application you need to identify which network protocol(s) will be used by the real users and go for [JMeter Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) (take a look at [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)) which support this(ese) protocol(s)
2. If you want to assess the performance of queries against MS Access directly you can use JMeter's [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler with a relevant JDBC driver like [UCanAccess](https://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) as it's described in [Building a Database Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) chapter of JMeter User Manual

Comment: Since Access is shared through SMB, which will cache (parts of) the file locally if a single PC is accessing it, your approaches will not really work and results will be over-optimisti. If you just simulate the SMB traffic, it won't properly capture issues with locking/conflicting reads and writes/corruption which can and will occur in multi-user access deployments. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I guess to access query and using JDBC connection config in jmeeter, i don't think connection string available to authenticate but certain i can try.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, load testing Access is not really feasible, and whenever you want to do this, you'd better look at a different backend.

The only supported way to make Access available to multiple users is through SMB, which will cache the file if a single computer is using it, and this process is built into Windows and not controllable through JMeter.

If you want proper load testing, that means you will need multiple computers accessing it with simulated, differing loads, with mixed read-write loads per machine (important, for proper simulation of database fragmenting and conflicting writes, which will occur frequently when an Access backend is used). These can be multiple Hyper-V machines on a virtual switch.

For even more fun, add in some simulated network instability, since Access is exceptionally terrible at handling that and it will frequently lead to corruption.

It is also important to note that Access has currently [unfixed issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-reports-that-databases-are-in-an-inconsistent-state-7ec975da-f7a9-4414-a306-d3a7c422dc1d) with corruption occurring in multi-user environments. Multi-user deployments are only feasible if you have control over the SMB server and can adapt its settings to avoid this issue.

So, while it could be done, in reality, if you have the resources to properly test Access, these will be far better spent moving to a different database system.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I can sense that it will be a expensive test if at all done so better invest mone to shift the application to better platform.

Answer (score 0):

Your limit is about ten.  There is no need to spend the labor testing this solution.   If you want scalable then you need a service based database, such as SQL Server in the Microsoft family, instead of a file based database.